# proxmox/terraform/cloud-init - incorrect ipconfig

Tags: terraform, cloud-init, proxmox

I am trying to build a VM on my Proxmox (from a template I created w Packer), and all is well except it does not take the IP I specified, but gets one from DHCP.

This is my provider config:

```
# Proxmox Provider
# ---
# Initial Provider Configuration for Proxmox

terraform {

    required_version = ">= 0.13.0"

    required_providers {
        proxmox = {
            source = "telmate/proxmox"
            version = "2.9.3"
        }
    }
}

variable "proxmox_api_url" {
    type = string
}

variable "proxmox_api_token_id" {
    type = string
}

variable "proxmox_api_token_secret" {
    type = string
}

provider "proxmox" {

    pm_api_url = var.proxmox_api_url
    pm_api_token_id = var.proxmox_api_token_id
    pm_api_token_secret = var.proxmox_api_token_secret

    # (Optional) Skip TLS Verification
    pm_tls_insecure = true

}
```

And this is my `.tf`

```
# Proxmox Full-Clone
# ---
# Create a new VM from a clone

resource "proxmox_vm_qemu" "doc-media-0" {

  # VM General Settings
  target_node = "proxmox01"
  vmid        = "100"
  name        = "doc-media-0"
  desc        = "Docker media server running on Ubuntu"

  # VM Advanced General Settings
  onboot = true

  # VM OS Settings
  clone = "ubuntu-server-jammy-docker"

  # The destination resource pool for the new VM
  pool = "prod"

  # VM System Settings
  agent = 1

  # VM CPU Settings
  cores   = 3
  sockets = 2
  cpu     = "host"

  # Storage settings
  disk {
    /* id           = 0 */
    type         = "virtio"
    storage      = "data-fast"
    /* storage_type = "directory" */
    size         = "20G"
    /* backup       = true */
  }

  # VM Memory Settings
  memory = 10240

  # VM Network Settings
  network {
    bridge = "vmbr0"
    model  = "virtio"
  }

  # VM Cloud-Init Settings
  os_type = "cloud-init"

  # (Optional) IP Address and Gateway
  ipconfig0 = "ip=192.168.1.20/16,gw=192.168.1.1"

  # (Optional) Name servers
  nameserver = "192.168.1.1"

  # (Optional) Default User
  ciuser = "fabrice"

  # (Optional) Add your SSH KEY
  sshkeys = <<EOF
  ssh-ed25519 <publick-ssh-key-removed>
  EOF

}
```

### Expected result

IP is 192.168.1.20

by virtue of `ipconfig0 = "ip=192.168.1.20/16,gw=192.168.1.1"`

### Actual result

VM got a DHCP address

[image]

What is odd, the other settings applied, so my gateway is correct, my user is there, and my publick ssh key

Answer (score 0):

Ignore me; I think it done it just not right after the tf completion.